# Remove border around page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this weird border around my entire page:

[image]

This is my App.js. The Home component has just ThemeProvider wrapper, and then everything is inside Paper component.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
         <div>
          <NavBar></NavBar>
        </div>
        <Home></Home>
      </ThemeProvider>   
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: try in CSS: body { overflow: hidden }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@khuynh has the right idea, however I'd suggest following Material-UI's recommendation to wrap your app in the [CSSBaseline](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/) component instead of manually attempting to provide your own browser resets.

Answer (score 3):

Most browsers have a default [user-agent stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#user-agent_stylesheets) where some default styles are applied. You want to explicitly set `body`'s margin and padding to 0px:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```